# Making a verification bot in Discord.py

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I am in progress of making a Discord bot. I would like the bot to send a direct message to newly joined members including their username and avatar. Then finding if the account is too new, as an anti raiding system in my Bot.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow! Could you provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code and any errors you got? We do not give code here, only help you improve what you already have. Please also visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info. All of the above will help you get a response faster. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria is not possible in Discord. Getting personal data (Users email address) from a Discord user is not possible what so ever. Discord would never let any user have access to private data in their API.

Fortunately, a much easier way of creating this is to check if the account was recently made. Using `member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))` will simply get the time and date the joined user created their account at. I'll leave it up to you when you want to set a threshold of how early a user can join.

You can also check when the user joined a server with, also remember to define the member as the Discord user who joined. I am leaving the rest for you to complete but hoping this helps get you farther in your progress. Next time, remember to include your trialed attempt and please don't always rely on the community to give you a whole code of answers.

```
member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
```